# show and hide div

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, show-hide

I have four different divs in my html that i want to keep hidden and then show the one of my choice depending on which link i click on. However, i cant hide them. It wont work, and i want whatever that is in respective div to be shown under the links, not next to them as they do now. My biggest difficaulty is to hide my divs, any solution?

Javascript

```
function show1(){
var minaP = document.getElementByID("one");
minaP.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function show2(){
var minaP = document.getElementById("two");
minaP.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function show3(){
var minaP = document.getElementById("three");
minaP.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function show4(){
var minaP = document.getElementById("four");
minaP.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function init() {

var minaDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(i=0; i<minaDiv.length; i++){
  minaDiv[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}

var minaA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(i=0; i<minaA.length; i++){
  if(document.getElementById == "1"){
    minaA.onclick = show1;
  }
}

}

window.onload = init;
```

Html

```
<div>
<ul class="meny">
<li><a href="#" id="1">Utvärdering/Feedback</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="2">Kontakt</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="3">Öppettider</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="4">Om Asperöd</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="one">
<p><b>Aperåd Äventyrsland</b></p> 
<p>Växel: 0200-123456999 (kl.08:30-15)</p>
<p>Stora Vägen 140</p>
<p>289 22 Aperöd</p>
<p>Skicka oss din <a href="#">fråga</a></p>
</div>
<div id="two">
<p>Du kan kontakta oss på följande nummer: 
<br> 040-123456
</p>
<p> Du kan även mejla oss:
<br> aperöd@hotmail.com
</p>
</div>
<div id="three">
<p>Vi har följande öppettider:</p>
<p> Mån-Fre: 10:00 - 20:00 </p>
<p> Lör: 10:00 - 18:00 </p>
</div>
<div id="four">
```

Aperöd är en fin park för alla möjliga personer. Vi erbjuder en massa, men det kostar      500kr
    
 för att delta för en dag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using/learning jQuery. It helps reducing code size and there are a lot of fancy animations ;)

Here a fast demo with `.hide() .show()`

http://jsfiddle.net/yFhX5/

Comment: wow, that was pretty easy and nice. though the content does not disappear when i click on a new link. it just falls after each other. other than that, nice intro. thanks

Comment: @DrWooolie you welcome. just an update with `.toggle` if you want to show/hide them http://jsfiddle.net/yFhX5/1/

Comment: @DrWooolie ... not sure, maybe you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/yFhX5/2/ ?

Comment: its not the code thats wrong, but when i implement it, it doesnt work. i have no clue why

Comment: @DrWooolie just include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` in your head HTML section

Comment: didnt work, even with that. this is what i had previously, <script type="text/javascript" src="Inl1-1.js" >
  </script> but none work. however your code works perfectly in jsfiddle

Comment: perhaps i didnt tell you, but my js code is supposed to be in an external file. thats why i dont know how to include it

Comment: @DrWooolie I think i know why! You need to wrap the code in a `$(document).ready(function() ... ` http://jsfiddle.net/yFhX5/3/

Comment: am i supposed to include both jsquery and my js file ? like this, <script type="text/javascript" src="Inl-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>, because either way, it wont work. im really starting to lose it haha sorry

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that you write the js code directly in your html. i have a seperate js file and have to include it like i include the jsquery. and when i do, i get the error, failed to load resource, and it refers to my js file

Comment: is it perhaps that im using <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> ? Because it is requirment

Comment: wow, i test your code and it works just fine. even though mine is exact the same, it wont work.

Comment: it works now, i misstyped when it came to ids. Im sorry about that. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Comment: can you help me with one last thing, i have also a css file which makes my links display block, float left. they are structured next to each other, and the content in every div doesnt show up under my links, but next to them. could you help me with that ?

Comment: this is how my css is structured:

Comment: .meny{ 
 float: left;
 font-size: 14pt;
 }
    
    .meny li{
 float: left;
 display: block; 
 list-style-type: none;}

    .meny a{
 padding: 0.35em 0.5em; 
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
  

    .meny a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;}

Comment: It would be churlish if I down voted this answer, but really, 'learn jquery' to hide a div? Import a library for a trivial function to 'reduce code size'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `style.display = 'none'`, not `style.visibility` and `style.display = 'block'` or `'inline'` to show them

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. Try running this small little script (F12 in chrome, then click "Console"): `document.getElementById('question').style.visibility = 'hidden'`

Comment: Try running document.getElementById('question').style.display = 'none', it works, as does the opposite.

Comment: 1 - The op's statement was that the code does not work, 2 - 'Property style of null' means you are doing a document.getElementById of an element that does not exist. .style.display works, I use it every single day!

Comment: Yeah i changed my id to an existing div. But i wonder why it wont work if i try with getElementsByTagName ? instead, i have to do this code 4 times, since i hav 4 divs

Comment: It should work if you use it with the array elements individually (as you did with visibilty, it will not work if applied to the entire array